# iTextSharp - How to generate a RTF document in the ClipBoard instead of a file

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, itext, rtf

I would like to generate a PDF or RTF document using iTextSharp library that can be copied to the clipboard, using the same code I use to generate the document on a file (FileStream).

This way my application would give the user two options: generate to a file or to the clipboard.

Comment: Where exactly do you intend to paste a PDF document?

Comment: I use the library iTextSharp to generate a RTF file. But I would like to generate the same content and send it to the clipboard, instead of sending it to a file.

Comment: How about along the lines of this article on System.Windows.Forms Cliboard object:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/clipboard01.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically every iTextSharp document is attached to a `System.IO.Stream`.

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
RtfWriter2.GetInstance(doc, stream);
```

Usually we save the document to a file, using `FileStream`. To use the same code to paste the document in the Clipboard, we use a `MemoryStream` instead.

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
RtfWriter2.GetInstance(doc, stream);

// (...) document content

doc.Close();

string rtfText = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
stream.Close();

Clipboard.SetText(rtfText, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
```

**I only had problems with Images:** It seems that iTextSharp exports images saving the bytes of the image after the `\bin` tag. Some libraries put the binary content encoded as hex characters. When I paste (from memory) in Word, the images won't appear, but if I load from a file, everything is OK. Any suggestions?