# Is there a way to make this faster? MemoryStream vs FileStream

Tags: c#, itext

I am working with iTextSharp, and need to generate hundreds of thousands of RTF documents - the resulting files are between 5KB and 500KB.

I am listing 2 approaches below - the original approach wasn't necessarily slow, but I figured why write and retrieve to/from file to get the output string I need. I saw this other approach using MemoryStream, but it actually slowed things down. I essentially just need the outputted RTF content, so that I can run some filters on that RTF to clean up unnecessary formatting. The queries bringing back the data are very quick instant seeming . To generate a 1000 files (actually 2000 files are created in process) with original approach files takes about 15 minutes, the same with second approach takes about 25-30 minutes. The resulting files that I've run are averaging around 80KB.

Is there something wrong with the second approach? Seems like it should be faster than the first one, not slower.

Original approach:

```
RtfWriter2.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(RTFFilePathName, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

   //Add Tables and stuff here

doc.Close(); //It saves a file here to (RTFPathFileName)

StreamReader srRTF = new StreamReader(RTFFilePathName);
string rtfText = srRTF.ReadToEnd();
srRTF.Close();

    //Do additional things with rtfText before writing to my final file
```

New approach, trying to speed it up but this is actually half as fast:

```
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  RtfWriter2.GetInstance(doc, stream);
  doc.Open();

     //Add Tables and stuff here

  doc.Close();

  string rtfText =
  ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
  stream.Close();


      //Do additional things with rtfText before writing to my final file
```

The second approach I am trying I found here:
[iTextSharp - How to generate a RTF document in the ClipBoard instead of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479050/itextsharp-how-to-generate-a-rtf-document-in-the-clipboard-instead-of-a-file)

Comment: How big is the file you are processing?  If it isn't very big then no it won't make much difference.  If it is big then you might not want to process it in-memory if it degrades your system too much.

Comment: Hello thank you for response. I have about 400,000 files I need to output - between 5KB and 500KB. I am using iTextSharp to generate RTF content from a SQL query.

Comment: Reuse the Memorystream. i.e. Allocate it once and use it for all files clearing it's contents in between.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on this code yet?  Don't guess where to optimize... KNOW where to optimize.

Answer (score 3):

How big your resulting stream is? MemoryStream performs a lot of memory copy operations while growing, so for large results it may take significantly longer to write data by small chunks compared with FileStream.

To verify if it is the problem set inital size of MemoryStream to some large value around  resulting size and re-run the code.

To fix it you can pre-grow memory stream initially (if you know approximate output) or write your own stream that uses different scheme when growing. Also using temporary file might be good enough for your purposes as is.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alexei said, its probably caused by fact, yo are creating MemoryStream every time, and every time it continously re-alocates memory as it grows. Try creating only 1 stream and reset it to begining before every write.

Also I think stream.GetBuffer() again returns new memory, so try using same StreamReader with your MemoryStream.

And it seems your code can be easily paralelised, so you can try run it using Paralel Extesions or using TreadPool.

And it seems little weird, you are writing your text as bytes in stream, then reading this stream as bytes and converting to text. Wouldnt it be possible to save your document directly as text?

Answer (score 0):

A MemoryStream is not associated with a file, and has no concept of a filename. Basically, you can't do that.

You certainly can't cast between them; you can only cast upwards an downwards - not sideways; to visualise:

```
    Stream
      |
```

---

|             |
FileStream    MemoryStream
You can cast a MemoryStream to a Stream trivially, and a Stream to a MemoryStream via a type-check; but never a FileStream to a MemoryStream. That is like saying a dog is an animal, and an elephant is an animal, so we can cast a dog to an elephant.

You could subclass MemoryStream and add a Name property (that you supply a value for), but there would still be no commonality between a FileStream and a YourCustomMemoryStream, and FileStream doesn't implement a pre-existing interface to get a Name; so the caller would have to explicitly handle both separately, or use duck-typing (maybe via dynamic or reflection).

Another option (perhaps easier) might be: write your data to a temporary file; use a FileStream from there; then (later) delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but there is a lot of misinformation in this thread.

It's all about buffer size.  The internal buffers are significantly smaller with a memory stream vs a file stream.  Smaller buffers cause more read\writes.

Just intilaize your memory stream with either a file stream or a byte array with a size of around 80k. Close the doc, set stream position to 0 and read to end the contents.

On a side note, get buffer will return the whole allocated buffer.  So if you only wrote 1 byte and the buffer is 4k, you will have a lot of garbage in your string.